# Bigquery wrapping on overflow operation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

For one of my projects, I need basic INT64 arithmetic operations that wrap on overflow.

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this than casting INT64 to NUMERIC?

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION INT64_WRAPPING_OVERFLOW(x NUMERIC) AS
(MOD(x+POW(CAST(2 as NUMERIC),63)+POW(CAST(2 as NUMERIC),64), POW(CAST(2 as NUMERIC),64))-POW(CAST(2 as NUMERIC),63));

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION WRAPPING_OVERFLOW_SUBTRACT(intA INT64, intB INT64) AS
(INT64_WRAPPING_OVERFLOW(CAST(intB as NUMERIC)-CAST(intA as NUMERIC)));

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION WRAPPING_OVERFLOW_ADD(intA INT64, intB INT64) AS
(INT64_WRAPPING_OVERFLOW(CAST(intB as NUMERIC)+CAST(intA as NUMERIC)));

SELECT
WRAPPING_OVERFLOW_SUBTRACT(9223372036854775807 , -9223372036854775808),
-- returns 1
WRAPPING_OVERFLOW_ADD(9223372036854775807 , 1),
-- returns -9223372036854775808
WRAPPING_OVERFLOW_SUBTRACT(-9223372036854775808 , 9223372036854775807),
-- returns -1
WRAPPING_OVERFLOW_ADD(-9223372036854775808 , -1),
-- returns 9223372036854775807
WRAPPING_OVERFLOW_SUBTRACT(-1 , 2),
-- returns 3
WRAPPING_OVERFLOW_ADD(2 , -1),
-- returns 1
WRAPPING_OVERFLOW_SUBTRACT(-43 , 45)
-- returns 88
```